# multiple threading and persistence best practices

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple threads (about 40) accessing persistent variables (strings and longs) for several hundred users in a java application.  What is the best way to store these variables?  Reading and writing to the variables could occur at any time, and i want to not only minimize CPU load but also reduce the effects when a variable is not available because it is being written.

I am thinking of creating a file for each user, converting all variables for that user into a string, and writing to or reading that file whenever I need a variable.

...or creating a HashMap for each user (key) and adding variables (values) as need be.

Is there a thread-safe way to do this, so as to ensure that whenever a thread requests a variable i can be sure it gets the correct value?

Thanks.

Comment: Ever heard of locking and synchronization?  Edit: First resource that comes to mind: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: I will research it.  Thanks.  Any other resources I can read?

Comment: Lots of them, but none that I can think of off the top of my head.  You can probably google around and find some endorsements for good books, or you can google around and find tutorials.  Really that link I pasted should cover all of your needs since accessing strings is very simple in the realm of concurrent problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know, I'm going to go out on a limb and say use a ConcurrentHashMap. It is one of the best ways to minimize contention with lots of concurrent info barring a Disruptor. Since you are considering a HashMap anyway, the benefit here is that the locking that occurs is limited to the individual hash rows--two items that hash to different regions do not block one another.

Comment: the best answer, and a ConcurrentHashMap seems to be working best.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your variables need to be stored (ie. non-volatile) I think you should just use an ACID DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL or whichever you prefer) and just let the DBMS handle the concurrency.

If you fear I/O will be a performance problem, most ORM frameworks provide both lazy reading mechanism and read/write caches that are also multi-thread safe (ie. [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/)).